# В шаге от того, чтобы (не) расплакаться

Tags: грамотная-речь

В значении "хочет заплакать, но ещё держится".
Нужна ли тут частица "не"? Вроде как по логике не нужна. Но "в шаге от того, чтобы расплакаться" звучит как-то криво.

Answer (score 1):

Да, частица не нужна. А криво звучит потому, что "шаг" ассоциируется с *сознательными* действиями - будто некто "подошёл" к тому, чтобы расплакаться. "На грани того, чтобы расплакаться" - получше, но естественнее сказать "был близок к тому, чтобы расплакаться", "готов был уже расплакаться" и т. п..

Answer (score 1):

**Если с не, то возможны варианты:**

Изо всех сил стараясь не расплакаться.

Еле сдерживался, чтобы не расплакаться.

Готов чуть ли не расплакаться.

Только бы не расплакаться.

"В шаге от..." ассоциируется с какой-то дистанцией, с протяжённостью пути к определённой цели, ср.: ***в шаге от победы, от пьедестала.*** Поэтому в рассматриваемой нами фразе выражение "в шаге от..." неуместно.

Comment: "В шаге от..." вполне употребимо для обозначения близости во времени какого-то события, ср.: **в шаге от катастрофы**.

Comment: Но тут близость не временная, а близость состояний. Какие тут могут быть шаги?!

Comment: @М_Г (Пропустил Ваш комментарий). Я не настаиваю на том, что здесь могут быть шаги (хотя мне это слух не режет). Но аргументация "протяжённости пути" / "близости состояний" меня не убеждает. Ср. "в шаге от обморока", "в шаге от комы", "в шаге от счастья" и т.п. Эти выражения активно используются носителями языка (в том числе в литературе). Если это неграмотно, хотелось бы услышать обоснование.

Comment: @grizzly Искал в Нацкорпусе, но Ваших примеров не  нашел. Мое ощущение (подтвежденное поиском в Нацкорпусе): шаг — это время, расстояние или действие, событие. С этой точки зрения можно принять даже "в шаге от того, чтобы расплакаться", но только в том случае, если ситуация зависела от чего-то, какого-то события или действия (например, еще оно слово — и я расплачусь)

Comment: @М_Г Хорошо, спасибо за разъяснения. Вероятно, в данном случае меня чувство языка подводит. Из сотни с лишним ссылок, которые я нашёл в Google или в библиотеках, практически всё либо журналистское либо самиздат. Единственное, на что я не постесняюсь сослаться — нормальное издание книги Умберто Эко, где использован подобный оборот: "в двух шагах от счастья" (см. следующий комментарий).

Comment: Ссылка на ["Остров на кануне"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=IQOEtdkUhLsC&pg=PT197&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85+%D0%BE%D1%82+%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDq7KQ077YAhXHalAKHV8rBOAQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F%22&f=false). Но я могу согласиться, что это скорее то исключение, которое подтверждает правило.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно люди стараются ***не расплакаться,*** поэтому без частицы НЕ предложение "звучит криво" даже при правильной грамматике.

Как вариант: **Я был шаге от того, чтобы чуть ли  не расплакаться.** (Я был готов чуть ли не расплакаться).